# CKEditor - Modify BBCode Output

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm building a forum application in php for my website (mostly just to see if I can pull it off). I've been tinkering with web development as a hobbyist for nearly 20 years, but I've always avoided working with javascript - meaning I've become pretty good working with html,css and php, but I'm useless when it comes to client-side scripting.

For all intents and purposes, my forum works. Users can register, post, edit, review an delete posts based on their user level and permissions etc. However I have an issue which is driving me crazy because I can't solve it:

I'm using CKEditor with the BBCode plugin as a WYSIWYG thread editor. On the server side I'm using a PEAR module for PHP to parse the BBCode and display the proper html. The PEAR module supports image tags in the following format `[img width={width} height={height}]{url}[/img]` but by default the BBCode plugin for CKEditor strips away the resizing functionality and will only allow me to use `[img]{url}[/img]` type tags.

I've managed to extend the plugin to process some other tags (s, sup, sub, font, etc.) but those are just a matter of adding them to the bbCode lists near the beginning of the plugin. img tags are handled differently, but without having a solid grasp on javascript I'm having a hard time fully understanding the source code to add my own logic. No matter what I do, the width and height properties get stripped away from the image tag.

Does anybody have a method of extending the CKEditor BBCode plugin so that I can retain the width and height attributes for images? I realize that similar questions have been asked before, but from what I can see none of them have been answered directly.

Here is a link to the CKEditor plugin: http://ckeditor.com/addon/bbcode (I'm using version 4.4.7)
and CKEditor itself: http://ckeditor.com/download (I'm using a full build of 4.4.7).

My bbcode map is:

```js
 var bbcodeMap = {
     b: 'strong',
     u: 'u',
     i: 'em',
     color: 'span',
     size: 'span',
     quote: 'blockquote',
     code: 'code',
     url: 'a',
     email: 'span',
     img: 'span',
     '*': 'li',
     list: 'ol',
     sup: 'sup',
     sub: 'sub',
     s: 's',
     font: 'span'
   },
   convertMap = {
     strong: 'b',
     b: 'b',
     u: 'u',
     em: 'i',
     i: 'i',
     code: 'code',
     li: '*',
     sup: 'sup',
     sub: 'sub',
     s: 's'
   },
   tagnameMap = {
     strong: 'b',
     em: 'i',
     u: 'u',
     li: '*',
     ul: 'list',
     ol: 'list',
     code: 'code',
     a: 'link',
     blockquote: 'quote',
     sup: 'superscript',
     sub: 'subscript',
     font: 'font',
     s: 'strike'
   },
   stylesMap = {
     color: 'color',
     size: 'font-size',
     font: 'font-family'
   },
   attributesMap = {
     url: 'href',
     email: 'mailhref',
     quote: 'cite',
     list: 'listType'
   };
```

The initialization HTML is:

```html
<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" name="post_content">

</textarea>

<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace('post_content', {
    extraPlugins: 'bbcode',
    // Remove unused plugins.
    removePlugins: 'bidi,dialogadvtab,div,filebrowser,flash,forms,format,horizontalrule,iframe,justify,liststyle,pagebreak,showborders,stylescombo,table,tabletools,templates',
    // Width and height are not supported in the BBCode format, so object resizing is disabled.
    disableObjectResizing: false,
    // Define font sizes in percent values.
    fontSize_sizes: "30/30%;50/50%;100/100%;120/120%;150/150%;200/200%;300/300%",
    toolbar: [
      ['Source', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
      ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat'],
      ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Image', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar'],
      ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Superscript', 'Subscript', 'Strike'],
      ['Font', 'FontSize'],
      ['TextColor'],
      ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Blockquote'],
      ['Maximize', '-', 'Preview']
    ],
    // Strip CKEditor smileys to those commonly used in BBCode.
    smiley_images: [
      'regular_smile.png', 'sad_smile.png', 'wink_smile.png', 'teeth_smile.png', 'tongue_smile.png',
      'embarrassed_smile.png', 'omg_smile.png', 'whatchutalkingabout_smile.png', 'angel_smile.png',
      'shades_smile.png', 'cry_smile.png', 'kiss.png'
    ],
    smiley_descriptions: [
      'smiley', 'sad', 'wink', 'laugh', 'cheeky', 'blush', 'surprise',
      'indecision', 'angel', 'cool', 'crying', 'kiss'
    ]
  });
</script>
```

Comment: did you find solution for this?